# ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

please how can I solve this error ?

> ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin
>   version 1.3.0 and higher. The following dependencies do not satisfy
>   the required version: root project 'android' ->
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.6 Affected Modules:
>   android-app
>
> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of
>   2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   Affected Modules: android-app
>
> WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'testImplementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   Affected Modules: android-app
>
> WARNING: Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'. It will be removed at the
>   end of 2018. For more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>   Affected Modules: android-app
>
> WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is
>   ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1. Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be
>   used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'"
>   from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle
>   Plugin now has a default version of the build tools. Remove Build
>   Tools version and sync project Affected Modules: android-app

my android-app file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.curie.jonquille.jonquille_curie"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 203000
        versionName "2.3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.4'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.60.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-kotlin:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4-kotlin:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7-kotlin:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design-kotlin:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7-kotlin:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.9.1@aar'
    compile 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location:0.10@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.sdoward:rxgooglemaps:1.1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-rxjava:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
```

my android file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.6'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error is caused by the old version of Kotlin in your project level file, you can update it to the latest version like so:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
```

As for your warnings:

- You should remove the explicit build tools version (`buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"`) from your module level file, as the new Android Gradle plugins already pick the correct build tools to use automatically.
- You should check out [the link in the warnings](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html) and update your dependency configuration, e.g. replace `compile` with `implementation` or `api`, and so on.

Comment: for those who did not understand it, i solved it in flutter, by going in specified plugin and in there app level gradle file you can find this. Hope this is helpful..