# Kotlin compile "ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher." but no kotlin_version in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I tried cloning and building this project, https://github.com/mitrejcevski/ui-testing, but upon opening it in Android Studio, I get the following build error:

```
ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'ui-testing' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.21
Affected Modules: app
```

However, when I click the 'app' hyperlink I am led to the module-level `build.gradle` file, which reads

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nl.jovmit"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        mock {
            flavorDimensions "default"
        }
        prod {
            flavorDimensions "default"
        }
    }

    android.variantFilter { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release' && variant.getFlavors().get(0).name == 'mock') {
            variant.setIgnore(true)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Unlike the accepted answer of [ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.0 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605954/error-the-android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-kotlin-gradle-plugin-version-1-3), I don't see any `ext.kotlin_version` anywhere in the Gradle file.

I do see this warning, though, that `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` is deprecated:

[image]

However, I tried changing this but still get the same error. I've also tried adding the line

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21'
```

to `dependencies` (as seen in the screenshot above), but that also didn't prevent the error.

Any idea how to fix this? I suspect that the outdated Kotlin version is a 'sub-dependency' of one of the dependencies here, but haven't been able to figure out which one.

Comment: Kotlin version is in project's build.gradle, not app's build.gradle.

Comment: Check your project's build.gradle. If you ever update kotlin version simply by clicking the prompt from Android Studio, you may end up with multiple `ext.kotlin_version='...'`. Remove all but the latest one.

Comment: I make some complements. 1.  The dependence should be in buildscript config body. Because is gradle plugin dependence for support kotlin compile (just like the name kotlin-gradle-plugin, more precise is for apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'), It's not your app dependence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change

> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version

instead of

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version
```

Comment: This is a part of the solution, check @SavedBeau solution

Comment: @AnasNaguib what is link of the solution, provided by SavedBeau. Please share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Define your `ext.kotlin_version`

Your project level build.gradle should look like this.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.android_plugin_version = '3.2.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: already defined `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'` and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'` and `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"` but still not working, any suggestion. Please share.

Comment: @Kamlesh did you find any solution?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to **Tools > SDK Manager > Kotlin**
2. Install new plugin version
3. Make sure your project level **build.gradle** looks as the one below

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10' //put the version you just updated to
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In react-native you need to use `ext.kotlinVersion` and NOT `ext.kotlin_version`.

Because all the dependancies try to get `rootProject.ext.kotlinVersion` for this reason if it is not found then they fallback to default. And for this reason you get the error of different Kotlin versions being used.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem too and I fixed it by doing the following:

- In project level build.gradle, I have ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.0'
}
```

- Then in app level build.gradle, I updated my dependencies to have this:
  `implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"`

I built, and everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 4):

Go to External Libraries / Flutter Plugins / ui_testing / android / build.gradle and changed ext.kotlin_version to LATEST_VERSION.

Comment: where is External Libraries?

Answer (score 4):

kotlinVersion='1.6.20' //add this line in android/build.gralde will resolve this issue.

//just like this

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
        kotlinVersion='1.6.20' 
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

## 2022 Solution for "Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin"

> In order to build a Kotlin project with Gradle, you should apply the Kotlin Gradle plugin to your project and configure the dependencies.
> In your root Project then Android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
    }
}
//$kotlin_version removed it to 1.5.31
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your project level build file
and change the following

```
 buildscript {
  ext {
kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
support_version = '28.0.0-rc02'
room_version = '1.1.1'
arch_comp_version = '1.1.1'
  }
 }
```

Just update kotlin version to 1.3.10 or higher.This would fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing this issue while using watermelondb.

I have resolved this issue by doing this

> npm install react-native-screens@3.13.1

```
buildscript{ ext {
      
        kotlinVersion = "1.5.20" //add this line in build.gradle file } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your kotlin dependency to:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.21"
```

Answer (score 0):

update your project level build.gradle
ext.kotlin_version = 'your_current_version' to ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

You can access last version => https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#targeting-the-jvm

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you've added `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'` and `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"` to Project/build.gradle and also enable  `multiDexEnabled true` in app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

```rb
   buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

node_modules > "Module causing error" > native > android > gradle.properties change the version to the latest one and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this in my Expo project by installing [expo-build-properties](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/), and adding this to my `app.json`:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "kotlinVersion": "1.6.21"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i solved by overriding the dependence in pubspec.yaml

```
  dependency_overrides:
    ui-testing:(specifiy the higher version)
```

then run

```
  flutter clean
  flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter,I checked the kotlin version from project/build.gradle - `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'` and then updated the package's kotlin version to match that. To locate the package's gradle file,you can click on the **.flutter-plugins** file generated at the root of your project

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jdk8 instead of jre7. So you should change

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version
```

to

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version
```